# Prove the following: $\int_{a}^{b}|f\left(t\right)|dt\leq\left(b-a\right)\int_{a}^{b}|f'\left(t\right)|dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I have this homework question and I'm in need of some assistance:

"Let there be a function $f:\left[a,b\right]
 \rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuously derivatable (every derivative is continuous), and $f(a)=0$. Prove the following:

$$\int_{a}^{b}|f\left(t\right)|dt\leq\left(b-a\right)\int_{a}^{b}|f'\left(t\right)|dt$$

Hint: Use the fact that $|f|$ is a continuous function, you can also use the following theorems (which were proved in earlier exercises):

1) $$|\int_{a}^{b}f\left(t\right)dt|\leq\int_{a}^{b}|f\left(t\right)|dt $$

2) $$\exists c\epsilon\left[a,b\right]\,\, s.t\,\,\int_{a}^{b}f\left(t\right)dt=f(c)(b-a)$$

I tried to play around with the hints and also with other theorems that I know, but I haven't made too much progress, my main problem is with the absolute values which seem to work against me each time I try something, its gotten to the point where I'm starting to confuse myself over nothing.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Use that $|f(t)|=\left|\int_a^t f'(x)dx\right|\leq (b-a)\int_a^b |f'(x)|dx $

Answer (score 5):

### This is Poincaré-Friedrich's inequality

By mean value theorem,since $f(a)=0$ such that
$$|f(t)|=\left|\int_a^t f'(x)dx\right|\leq \int_a^b |f'(x)|dx$$

by integrating against t variable we get, $$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt\leq (b-a)\int_a^b |f'(x)|dx$$
this shows that, $$\|f\|_{L^1(a,b)}\leq (b-a)\|f'\|_{L^1(a,b)}$$

> More generally we can drop the condition that $f(a)=0. $
> Indeed, By mean value theorem, there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that
> $$f(c) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$$
> By fundamental theorem of calculus for all $t$, we have
> $$ f(t)=f(c)+\int_c^t f'(x)dx= \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx+\int_c^t f'(x)dx$$ taking the supremum implies

$$\|f\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\leq (b-a)^{-1}\|f\|_{L^1(a,b)}+\|f'\|_{L^1(a,b)}= ((b-a)^{-1}+1)\|f\|_{W^{1,1}(a,b)}$$ that is
$$\|f\|_{L^\infty(a,b)}\leq C\|f\|_{W^{1,1}(a,b)}.$$

Comment: There is something wrong with the last equation on the yellow box. Essentially it says that if we drop the condition that $f(a)=0$,then $f(t)\le\int_a^b|f'(x)|dx$, which in general is false. For example if $f(t)=1$, so $f'(t)=0$, this will give $1\le0$.

Comment: @AndersBeta that inequality is supposed to  there thank I reomved it